# Is there a solution to a combination NAS/media server, gaming server, and mobile device media streamer?

Tags: nas, home-server

**Summary:**

Can I accomplish the following with one old PC in a limited number of headaches:

1. NAS device for back up/media serving.
2. Game server.
3. Mobile device media streamer.
4. Access remotely.

---

**Full Question:**

The situation is as follows:
I have finally replaced the clunky desktop at home with a sleek new HTPC box I built to handle all of my HTPC needs.  The old desktop is now to be repurposed into some sort of NAS monster.

Here's the catch: I would like it to be put to use for the following purposes:

1. NAS device.  It will backup/serve of my media files, act as redundant storage, and so forth for my LAN.  The HTPC will be tapping into it, as well as a couple laptops.  I'd like to also use it for a UPnP, but I suspect that will be an easy trick.
2. Gaming server.  From time to time I use it as a host for various older game servers, ventrilo, and the like.  I'd like to continue doing so, since the HTPC will be moved around and might be a bit inconsistant for this.
3. Mobile media streamer.  I have seen various software for serving across the net to mobile devices so I can listen to music and watch videos away from home.
4. Remote access.  I'd like to be able to access my files, watch videos, and back up from remote locations when I'm not at home.  VPN is the first thought.

Is there a way to accomplish all this in one unit?  Everything I've looked at thus far seems to hit one or two of these, but misses all of them (for example FreeNAS works well for a NAS device, but would prevent the other uses).  I have access to XP and 7, and I'm willing to use *nix.

Comment: Take a look at Amahi HDA

Comment: @uSlackr Almost perfect, but it doesn't appear that I can use the computer as a server for games and the like using that software (unless I'm misreading it, which is certainly possible).  Would that be true?

Comment: It's a fedora (and soon Ubuntu) install.  You can install anything you like on it assuming you know Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Amahi on my home server.  Its Greyhole technology gives you drive pooling without using RAID.  I've added a couple of apps on my own (not through the store) including subsonic which does the streaming.  not sure what you need to make it a game server, but if it is available for linux, you are all set as it runs on a Fedora base (soon to add Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use Windows 7 Ultimate, with only 1.5GB of DDR RAM (Note to any other computer junkies: I'm willing to take your old stuff if it's an upgrade), and 2 NICs. It has 5 HDDs (1 20GB IDE for the boot, 2 500GB IDE in RAID 0, 2 1TB SATA HDDs in RAID 0), and I can remote desktop to it. I set it up as a VPN server, and until Telus (my Cell provider) changed their rules, I used to connect all the time to home using Remote Potato for my media and my VPN.

The game server will depend on what games you want to play; I only ever hosted Half Life with their Dedicated Server software, no mods or anything